# How to Add OnTouchListener and OnClickListener at a time in Linear Layout?

Tags: android, layout, onclicklistener, ontouchlistener

How can I add a event `OnTouchListener` and `OnclickListener` at a time in `LinearLayout`?

Here is my code but doesn't work

```
final LinearLayout llTimeTable=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llSehriIftar);
    llTimeTable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Ramadandate.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
    llTimeTable.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            llTimeTable.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(51, 51, 255));
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                // set color back to default
                llTimeTable.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(76, 106, 225));

                break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

But when I only use `OnclickListener` it works, and when I use only `onTouch` method it works, but both at the same time doesn't work.

Comment: Your concept is not clear for touch and click please read it first

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578718/how-to-combine-onclicklistener-and-ontouchlistener-for-an-imagebutton

Comment: You may take a look at this. I think it is helpful to grasp the onTouch vs onClick
http://stackoverflow.com/a/9123001/1239911

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since Touch Event is more general, it is called first, then the `onClick` gets fired, however, since  your onTouch returns true, the event is consumed and `onClick` is never reached.

Simply change **`onTouch`** to **`return false`** and your onClick will be called.

Comment: Thanks :) New user on stackoverflow, I appreciate it as it will help me get access to more features on the site

Answer (score 4):

```
 llTimeTable.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        //Your code.......
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Make sure you return false in the `TouchListener` becuase if you return true then that event will not be passed to other listeners.